# Is there a support to embed Medium feed to Angular

Tags: angular

I am about to embed the Medium blog to my website.

I saw there is this cool vue thingie: https://github.com/chrisj74/vue-rss-blog

But no luck finding something like that for angular.

Or should I'll be looking for something more general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I failed to find a tool so I build one:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-medium

Comment: Great and simple solution. Thanks, @Pavel!